# Cluster in yellow state because of .kibana index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

The cluster is in yellow state because there are two indices that need replication but for some reason they don't replicate. Those two indices are:

```
.kibana_1
.kibana_2
```

I have tried setting replicas to zero for those indices but that doesn't seem to work.

```
PUT .kibana_1/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  }
}
```

Everything else is ok, green. I have tried restarting kibana, and also restarting all the nodes of the cluster. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (https://discuss.elastic.co/t/change-number-of-replicas-to-0-on-existing-indices/141622/14)

You have to set another setting for that index on the same request:

```
PUT .kibana_1/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "auto_expand_replicas": false
  }
}
```

With `number_of_replicas: 0` and `auto_expand_replicas: false` it is now green.